# Inserting into database using pushbutton creates TypeError: argument 1 must be str, not tuple

Tags: python, sqlite

I am having trouble making a pushbutton to insert elements into the table. Error states TypeError: argument 1 must be str, not tuple. I tried to convert it into int and do str but it keeps generating different errors. Could I get please get help figuring out what I have to do?

Below are my code and screenshot of DB and application

```
class MyCatScreen(QDialog):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MyCatScreen, self).__init__()
        loadUi("myCatScreen.ui", self)
        self.tableWidget.setColumnWidth(0,169)
        self.tableWidget.setColumnWidth(1,169)
        self.tableWidget.setColumnWidth(2,169)
        self.tableWidget.setColumnWidth(3,169)
        self.tableWidget.setHorizontalHeaderLabels(["Cat ID", "Cat Name", "Cat Age", "Cat Weight"])
        self.loaddata()

        self.catAdd.clicked.connect(self.addToDB)

    def loaddata(self):
        connection = sqlite3.connect('petData.db')
        cur = connection.cursor()
        # global cursor
        # cursor = connection.cursor()
        sqlquery = 'SELECT * FROM Cat_Info'

        #numRow = cur.execute("SELECT count(Cat_ID) FROM Cat_Info")
        #print(numRow)

        #Attention needed!
        #This needs to be changed to allocate dynamically
        self.tableWidget.setRowCount(10)
        tableRow = 0
        for row in cur.execute(sqlquery):
            print(row)
            self.tableWidget.setItem(tableRow, 0, QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem(str(row[0])))
            self.tableWidget.setItem(tableRow, 1, QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem(str(row[1])))
            self.tableWidget.setItem(tableRow, 2, QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem(str(row[2])))
            self.tableWidget.setItem(tableRow, 3, QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem(str(row[3])))
            tableRow+=1

    def addToDB(self):
        name = self.catName.text()
        age = self.catAge.text()
        weight = int(self.catWeight.text())
        newCat = (name, str(age), str(weight))
        connection = sqlite3.connect('petData.db')
        cur = connection.cursor()
        sqlquery = 'INSERT into Cat_Info (Cat_Name, Cat_Age, Cat_Weight) VALUES(?,?,?),', (newCat)

        cur.execute(sqlquery)
```

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\documents\sideProject\pyqt5\CatCare\main.py", line 126, in addToDB
    cur.execute(sqlquery)
TypeError: argument 1 must be str, not tuple
```

[application](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fGYoE.png)

[SQLite DB](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AZrDp.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the error resides in how you executing queries

Here's how it has to be

```
sqlquery = 'INSERT into Cat_Info (Cat_Name, Cat_Age, Cat_Weight) VALUES(?,?,?),' <-- no parameters here
cur.execute(sqlquery, (name, age, weight))
```

It must be something in how your variables name, age, and weight defined, since you're still getting problems.

For example, this code works for me:

```
connection = sqlite3.connect('petData.db')
cur = connection.cursor()

# cur.execute('create table Cat_Info (Cat_Name, Cat_Age, Cat_Weight)')
name = 'cat1'
age = 1
weight = 10
sqlquery = 'insert into cat_info(cat_name, cat_age, cat_weight) values(?, ?, ?)'

cur.execute(sqlquery, (name, age, weight))
connection.commit()

for row in cur.execute('SELECT * FROM cat_info'):
  print(row)
```

So, check out those variables' types

Comment: Thank you for answering. However, I am getting TypeError: argument 1 must be str, not tuple after the change. Do you have advice?

Comment: @reksapj here, I've updated my answer. If this won't work, then I'm out of ideas

Comment: Now I am getting sqlite3.OperationalError: incomplete input.. But thank you for trying to help me!

Comment: Hmmm. That's strange. I'll get back to you in some time if you won't get an answer from someone else

Comment: @reksapj updated my question with a working example. I think it is something strange with how your variables are defined. Try to find out what type they are of

Comment: Wow that worked for me! Thank you! I also had to delete int from weight = self.catWeight.text(). Thank you for your time and effort!

Comment: @reksapj you're always welcome. If probem solved, please don't forget to mark this as an answer

Comment: Just did it! Thank you again!!